# Cannot determine if type of field in a Pydantic model is of type List

Tags: python, python-typing, pydantic

I am trying to automatically convert a Pydantic model to a DB schema. To do that, I am recursively looping through a Pydantic model's fields to determine the type of field.

As an example, I have this simple model:

```py
from typing import List
from pydantic import BaseModel

class TestModel(BaseModel):
    tags: List[str]
```

I am recursing through the model using the `__fields__` property as described here: https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#model-properties

If I do `type(TestModel).__fields__['tags']` I see:

```py
ModelField(name='tags', type=List[str], required=True)
```

I want to programatically check if the `ModelField` type has a `List` origin. I have tried the following, and none of them work:

- `type(TestModel).__fields__['tags'].type_ is List[str]`
- `type(TestModel).__fields__['tags'].type_ == List[str]`
- `typing.get_origin(type(TestModel).__fields__['tags'].type_) is List`
- `typing.get_origin(type(TestModel).__fields__['tags'].type_) == List`

Frustratingly, this does return `True`:

- `type(TestModel).__fields__['tags'].type_ is str`

What is the correct way for me to confirm a field is a `List` type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pydantic has the concept of the **shape** of a field. These shapes are encoded as integers and available as constants in the [`fields`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.4/pydantic/fields.py#L334) module. The more-or-less standard types have been accommodated there already. If a field was annotated with `list[T]`, then the `shape` attribute of the field will be **`SHAPE_LIST`** and the `type_` will be `T`.

The `type_` refers to the **element** type in the context of everything that is not `SHAPE_SINGLETON`, i.e. with container-like types. This is why you get `str` in your example.

Thus for something as simple as `list`, you can simply check the shape against that constant:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.fields import SHAPE_LIST


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    tags: list[str]
    other: tuple[str]


tags_field = TestModel.__fields__["tags"]
other_field = TestModel.__fields__["other"]
assert tags_field.shape == SHAPE_LIST
assert other_field.shape != SHAPE_LIST
```

If you want more insight into the actual **annotation** of the field, that is stored in the `annotation` attribute of the field. With that you should be able to do all the `typing` related analyses like [`get_origin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin).

That means another way of accomplishing your check would be this:

```py
from typing import get_origin

from pydantic import BaseModel


class TestModel(BaseModel):
    tags: list[str]
    other: tuple[str]


tags_field = TestModel.__fields__["tags"]
other_field = TestModel.__fields__["other"]

assert get_origin(tags_field.annotation) is list
assert get_origin(other_field.annotation) is tuple
```

Sadly, neither of those attributes are officially documented anywhere as far as I know, but the beauty of open-source is that we can just check ourselves. Neither the attributes nor the shape constants are obfuscated, protected or made private in any of the usual ways, so I'll assume these are stable (at least until Pydantic v2 drops).

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! I did try and look at the code originally but I failed to find where the definition of `ModelField` was. I'm not that competent when it comes to python, so my original guess was that the code may be in [`/pydantic/fields`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/fields.py). Where did you happen to find it?

Comment: @rbhalla Ah, that is where the `ModelField` definition is. But you were looking at the `main` branch and that is already on its way to v2. Apparently in v2 `ModelField` is moved somewhere else. If look a the latest [`1.10.4`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.4/pydantic/fields.py) tag, you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

While Daniil's answer is more pydantic, to answer your OP, just get the `.annotation` attr (or property-method?) on the Field.

Like so,

```py
>>> class Foo(BaseModel):
...     x: Optional[dict[str,list[int]]]
...
>>> Foo.__fields__
... typing.Optional[dict[str, list[int]]]
```

Then do whatever work you want with the annotations by accessing their inner subscript `__args__`